# Gitlab CI - Cannot get local includes to work

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

Gitlab version: 14.3.3

I cannot get all jobs to be created and work in the pipeline. I get an infinite load on running pipelines.

I'm expecting

On a MR

1. build:merge-request-pipeline-dynamic_script
2. build:shared-pipeline-dump-variables
3. test:shared-pipeline-test-job-artifacting-always
4. test:shared-pipeline-test-job-artifacting-always-multi

On Main

1. build:main-pipeline-dynamic_script
2. build:shared-pipeline-dump-variables
3. test:shared-pipeline-test-job-artifacting-always
4. test:shared-pipeline-test-job-artifacting-always-multi

```
# .gitlab-ci.yml

image: ruby:2.3

# Global rules on all pipelines
workflow:
  rules:
    # Mask and prevent builds on noci commit SHA's
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TITLE =~ /^noci/
      when: never

# Specific pipelines with specific rules
include:
  - local: main-pipeline.yml
    rules:
      # Any commits to `main` i.e. we have merged something in
      - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  - local: merge-request-pipeline.yml
    rules:
      # Merge requests going in will build
      - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
  # Catch all pipeline that will just build everything that we want all the time
  # NB: This will obviously only be included if we pass the global workflow check
  - local: shared-pipeline.yml
```

```
# main-pipeline.yml

variables:
  BUILD_TYPE: commit to main

main-pipeline-dynamic_script:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Were running directly in main!"
    - echo "USER VARIABLE LIST (SHOULD BE PRESENT) - BUILD_TYPE - $BUILD_TYPE"
```

```
# merge-request-pipeline.yml

variables:
  BUILD_TYPE: merge-request

merge-request-pipeline-dynamic_script:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Were running on a merge request!"
    - echo "USER VARIABLE LIST (SHOULD BE PRESENT) - BUILD_TYPE - $BUILD_TYPE"
```

```
# shared-pipeline.yml

variables:
  NO_DEFAULT:
    description: This has no default. It should interpolate as blank.
  WITH_DEFAULT:
    description: This has a default. It should interpolate as default.
    value: default

shared-pipeline-dump-variables:
  stage: build
  script:
    # ... removed not important

shared-pipeline-test-job-artifacting-always:
  stage: test
  script:
    - # redundant

shared-pipeline-test-job-artifacting-always-multi:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "This job will artifact logs"
    - echo "log1" > log1.log
    - echo "log2" > log2.log
    - # removed redundant
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - log1.log
      - log2.log
      - log3.log
      - log/log4.log
      - log/log5.log
      - log/log6doesnotexist.log
```